# How to pass a letter to the abaqus datacheck using here strings through a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, tty, abaqus

This question is about passing input to commands inside a bash script. I am working on Ubuntu 18.04. I am running the following command several times inside a folder :

`abaqus datacheck job=Job input=inputfile.inp user=umat.f`

Every time I do it asks me if I want to overwrite the existing job files (y/n) ? and I type y and press enter. I was able to automate this last step using the following tweak with a here string on the terminal prompt :

`abaqus datacheck job=Job input=inputfile.inp user=umat.f <<< 'y'`

But when I include this in a bash script as part of a larger automation file, it doesn't work. This command using a here doc doesn't work inside the bash script either :

```
abaqus datacheck job=Job input=inputfile.inp user=umat.f << EOF
y
EOF
```

What did work : I put the single character `y` inside a text file called `affirmative` and passed that as a here doc :

`abaqus datacheck job=Job input=inputfile.inp user=umat.f << affirmative`

Could someone please tell what I am doing wrong in the bash script when trying to use a simple here doc or a here string ? I don't want to have a text file in my folder just for one character.

Comment: Why not just `abaqus ... ask_delete=OFF ...`?

Comment: This seems to be what I need. However, when I run this from the command line it works fine. But when I include it in a script and run that script, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really important to be limited by a bash script? If not, you can use this solution with python scripting:

#### 1. Launching the bash command via subprocess

```py
import subprocess
my_cmd = 'abaqus job=Job-1 input=inputfile.inp user=umat.f'

proc = subprocess.Popen(
   my_cmd,
   cwd=my_working_dir,
   stdout='my_study.log',
   stderr='my_study.err',
   shell=True
)
```

#### 2a. Running different jobs using different job names (`Job-1`, `Job-2`)

and deleting old ones with a delay (e.g. deleting 'Job-1' while 'Job-3' has started)

#### 2b. Writing to the command line

By adding an option `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` to your `subprocess.Popen` call and using `proc.stdin.write("y")` command after

Personally, I like more the first option as it seems more predictable to me.